# When I try to deploy my PHP application to Google App Engine, why am I suddenly getting a 400 error?

Tags: php, google-app-engine

Running the deploy command:

```
appcfg.py update ./appengine-project
```

I started seeing this error:

```
Error 400: --- begin server output ---
PHP 5.4 applications are prevented from being deployed to Google App
Engine from any version of the SDK, including older ones. If you need
to continue to deploy PHP 5.4 applications for compatibility reasons, 
you can request that your application be whitelisted for PHP 5.4
deployment by visiting http://goo.gl/qjKEuk.
--- end server output ---
```

I am running PHP 5.5 locally. And I deployed my application just a couple days ago without issue.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[This Google Groups post here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-appengine/9PMjrTxVy4w/jXhJHOmRSgkJ) got me sorted out.

In my `app.yaml` file, I just needed to change this line:

```
runtime: php
```

to:

```
runtime: php55
```

After that, the deploy succeeded.

Comment: Surprising how difficult this can be. When Google were moving out of php5.4 why they could not directly state in their email what kind of changes you need to do in your configuration file to enable latest php version support.

Comment: You can't use php55 with SDK.1.9.17 and lower.You need to update it.