# Google cloud "This application does not exist (app_id=u'sunlit-precinct-93807')"

Tags: wordpress, shell, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to setup a Wordpress installation on Google cloud by the hand of this tutorial: https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project/

I have successfully created a database, now I want to deploy the files to the server (tried it with Google Launcher and with terminal command), but it gives me the following response:

```
This application does not exist (app_id=u'sunlit-precinct-93807').
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. My application has a status running here: https://appengine.google.com and in my cloud console as well.

```
$ appcfg.py update /Users/639/Desktop/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project_build_linux_mac 
12:41 PM Application: sunlit-precinct-93807; version: wpfromstarterproject
12:41 PM Host: appengine.google.com
12:41 PM 
Starting update of app: sunlit-precinct-93807, version: wpfromstarterproject
12:41 PM Getting current resource limits.
12:41 PM Scanning files on local disk.
12:41 PM Scanned 500 files.
12:41 PM Scanned 1000 files.
Error 404: --- begin server output ---
This application does not exist (app_id=u'sunlit-precinct-93807').
--- end server output ---
iMac-van:~ 639$ appcfg.py update /Users/639/Desktop/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project_build_linux_mac 
12:42 PM Application: sunlit-precinct-93807; version: wpfromstarterproject
12:42 PM Host: appengine.google.com
12:42 PM 
Starting update of app: sunlit-precinct-93807, version: wpfromstarterproject
12:42 PM Getting current resource limits.
12:42 PM Scanning files on local disk.
12:42 PM Scanned 500 files.
12:42 PM Scanned 1000 files.
Error 404: --- begin server output ---
This application does not exist (app_id=u'sunlit-precinct-93807').
--- end server output ---
```

Answer (score 1):

Double check the following:

1. You application ID is correct and matches exactly with what you see in cloud console.
2. Your app.yaml file might be having special characters so instead of copy pasting application ID, try typing it.

Comment: Thansk for your answer. I typed the ID, but got the same problem. I have one double-check question. Is application ID the project ID.

Comment: I also tried it with a new app.yaml file and new project as well, but have the same problem.

Comment: By following this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039200/this-application-does-not-exist-app-id-xxx?rq=1 and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30045149/when-i-try-to-deploy-my-php-application-to-google-app-engine-why-am-i-suddenly I figured it out!