# After Google App Engine SDK update not able to run local server through PHPStorm 8?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, phpstorm

After updating Google App Engine SDK to 1.9.20 I am unable to run local server through PHPStorm 8. I get the following error:

```
The PHP interpreter specified with the --php_executable_path flag 

("/usr/local/bin/php-cgi") is not compatible with the App Engine PHP development environment.

Unable to load GAE runtime module at /Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/php55/gae_runtime_module.so
```

I am running following versions locally

php --version

```
PHP 5.5.22 (cli) (built: Mar 10 2015 14:17:46) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.7, Copyright (c) 2002-2015, by Derick Rethans
```

php-cgi --version

```
PHP 5.5.22 (cgi-fcgi) (built: Mar 10 2015 14:17:49)
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.7, Copyright (c) 2002-2015, by Derick Rethans
```

[image]
Here is the error I am getting through PHPStorm:

```
ERROR    2015-05-18 11:30:04,783 php_runtime.py:353] The PHP runtime is not 

available
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/php_runtime.py", line 349, in new_instance
    self._check_binaries(php_executable_path, gae_extension_path)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/php_runtime.py", line 290, in _check_binaries
    cls._check_gae_extension(php_executable_path, gae_extension_path, env)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/php_runtime.py", line 252, in _check_gae_extension
    gae_extension_path)
_PHPEnvironmentError: Unable to load GAE runtime module at /Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/php55/gae_runtime_module.so
```

To my understanding, PHP version 5.5 should be supported, where is the problem?

Comment: I found out that it seems the issue is with the Google App Engine app.yaml in my project folder. I had to change a few days ago `runtime: php` to `runtime: php55` as pointed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30045149/when-i-try-to-deploy-my-php-application-to-google-app-engine-why-am-i-suddenly) But now it causes problems with running stuff locally, wtf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're running on Mac, simply remove the "Path to php-cgi executable" setting in PHPStorm should fix the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work as it complains then "Error: Please specify a valid php-cgi executable path"

Comment: In that case you'll need to specify /Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/php55/php-cgi

Comment: Thanks @Mars, that solved it for me. And apparently Google SDK did not like PHP version 5.5.22 that I had as the one in SDK folder is 5.5.23

Comment: There are some fairly specific requirements for the PHP interpreter for it to work with the SDK. That is why we bundle pre-built binaries with Mac & Windows SDKs. We're also in the process of documenting how to build your own PHP interpreter and GAE extension for Linux users.

Comment: @Mars - Is there a currently open app engine ticket to track this work being done?  I think the folks over at homebrew-php should know about it.

Comment: We have an internal bug tracking that. Feel free to create an issue at https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list?can=2&q=Language=PHP